# Nested iteration over infinite streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream, for-comprehension

I sometimes find myself wanting to perform nested iterations over infinite streams in Scala **for** comprehensions, but specifying the loop termination condition can be a little tricky. Is there a better way of doing this kind of thing?

The use case I have in mind is where I don't necessarily know up front how many elements will be needed from each of the infinite streams I'm iterating over (but obviously I know it's not going to be an infinite number). Assume the termination condition for each stream might depend on the values of other elements in the for expression in some complicated way.

The initial thought is to try to write the stream termination condition as an **if** filter clause in the **for** expression, however this runs into trouble when looping over nested infinite streams, because there's no way of short-circuiting the iteration over the first infinite stream, which ultimately leads to an OutOfMemoryError. I understand why this is the case, given how **for** expressions map to **map**, **flatMap** and **withFilter** method calls - my question is whether there's a better idiom for doing this kind of thing (perhaps not involving **for** comprehensions at all).

To give a somewhat contrived example to illustrate the issue just described, consider the following (very naive) code to generate all pairings of the numbers 1 and 2:

```
val pairs = for {
  i <- Stream.from(1) 
  if i < 3 
  j <- Stream.from(1) 
  if j < 3
} 
yield (i, j)

pairs.take(2).toList 
// result: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2)) 

pairs.take(4).toList
// 'hoped for' result: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2))
// actual result:
//  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
//      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$.from(Stream.scala:1105)
```

Obviously, in this simple example, the problem could easily be averted by moving the **if** filters into **takeWhile** method calls on the original streams, as follows:

```
val pairs = for {
  i <- Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ < 3) 
  j <- Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ < 3) 
}    
yield (i, j)
```

but for the purposes of the question imagine a more complex use case where the stream termination condition can't easily be moved onto the stream expression itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted Petr's suggestion to come up with what I think is a more generally usable solution, in that it doesn't place restrictions on the positioning of **if** filters in the for comprehension (although it has a little more syntactic overhead).

The idea is again to enclose the underlying stream in a wrapper object, which delegates the `flatMap`, `map` and `filter` methods without modification, but first applies a `takeWhile` call to the underlying stream, with a predicate of `!isTruncated`, where `isTruncated` is a field belonging to the wrapper object. Calling `truncate` on the wrapper object at any point will flip the `isTruncated` flag and effectively terminate further iteration over the stream.  This relies heavily on the fact that the `takeWhile` call on the underlying stream is lazily evaluated, so it is possible for code executed at later stages of the iteration to affect its behaviour.

The downside is you have to hold on to references to the streams you want to be able truncate mid-iteration, by appending  `|| s.truncate` to the filter expression (where `s` is the reference to the wrapped stream). You also need to make sure you call `reset` on the wrapper object (or use a new wrapper object) before each new iteration through the stream, unless you know that the repeat iterations will behave identically each time through.

```
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.generic._

class TruncatableStream[A]( private val underlying: Stream[A]) {
  private var isTruncated = false;

  private var active = underlying.takeWhile(a => !isTruncated)

  def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Stream[A], B, That]): That = active.flatMap(f);

  def map[B, That](f: (A) => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Stream[A], B, That]): That = active.map(f);

  def filter(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = active.filter(p);

  def truncate() = {
    isTruncated = true
    false
  }

  def reset() = {
    isTruncated = false
    active = underlying.takeWhile(a => !isTruncated)
  }
}

val s1 = new TruncatableStream(Stream.from(1))
val s2 = new TruncatableStream(Stream.from(1))

val pairs = for {
  i <- s1

  // reset the nested iteration at the start of each outer iteration loop 
  // (not strictly required here as the repeat iterations are all identical)
  // alternatively, could just write: s2 = new TruncatableStream(Stream.from(1))  
  _ = _s2.reset()      

  j <- s2
  if i < 3 || s1.truncate
  if j < 3 || s2.truncate
} 
yield (i, j)

pairs.take(2).toList  // res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2))
pairs.take(4).toList  // res2: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2))
```

No doubt this could be improved upon, but it seems a reasonable solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer for the time being, as it provides a generally applicable solution to the problem posed, but will happily reassign it if a better solution appears.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to wrap `Stream` into your own class that handles `filter` differently, in this case, as `takeWhile`:

```
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.generic._

class MyStream[+A]( val underlying: Stream[A] ) {
  def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Stream[A], B, That]): That = underlying.flatMap(f);

  def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Stream[A], B, That]): That = underlying.map(f);

  def filter(p: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = underlying.takeWhile(p);
  //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

object MyStream extends App {
  val pairs = for {
    i <- new MyStream(Stream.from(1))
    if i < 3
    j <- new MyStream(Stream.from(1))
    if j < 3
  } yield (i, j);

  print(pairs.toList);
}
```

This prints `List((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2))`.

Comment: That's a good idea, although it will only work if the filter expression immediately follows the stream expression to which the filter applies (in which case you may as well just use 'takeWhile' directly). For example, if you swap the line 'if i < 3' in your example with the line below it, then you once again end up with an OutOfMemoryError.